# Get the fraction of values that's less than a constant for all columns in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, summary

I think there should be a really easy way to do this but I'm not that skilled in R yet. My dumb solution is just to iterate through the columns, count the number of values that's less than C, divide it by the number of rows to get the fraction. Something like

```
fracs <- c()
for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
  frac <- sum(df[,j] < C) / nrow(df)
  fracs <- c(fracs, frac)
}
```

I feel there should be a one-liner to get this kind of summary for a data frame, perhaps using dplyr or something. Ideally the output is a data frame of one row with the fractions. R masters please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be very simple. I think you just want `colMeans(df < C)`

Edit: just to be a little more clear, `df` is a dataframe. When we run `df < C`, the results will be a logical matrix of the same dimensions, where each cell, i,j, stores the result of `df[i,j] > C`. `colMeans` takes the column means, treating `TRUE` and `FALSE` as 1 and 0, respectively.

Comment: Wow thanks for the super quick and awesome answer. It makes me feel so dumb. Your answer is so quick it won't even allow me to accept now. Will accept in 10 min.

Comment: It's just experience, but I'm glad it helped you. I'm going to expand on it, because I think the answer was too brief.

Comment: this is one of those solutions that's so elegant, but not obvious on it's face